# Text formatting textbox to conform with time vb.net

Tags: vb.net, textbox, text-formatting

I have the following code with which I'm trying to format the text to conform with (time based) minutes and I suppose I will reuse this for the seconds later on also. first I want to establish that my minutes fall within the range of 0-59 (this part works fine) then I want to get all the minutes ranging from 0-9 and if they have one digit example being 0,1,2,3,4,5 ect... I want to add a prefixed 0 so that these then become 01,02,03,04,05 ect.... This is where my problem starts first off if a user enters 01 that 01 then becomes 001 and if for some reason the user enters 10 that 10 also becomes 01 can someone help me untangle this problem?

```
   Private Sub TextBox13_Leave(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox13.Leave

   If IsNumeric(TextBox13.Text) Then
        If TextBox13.Text >= CStr(0) Or TextBox13.Text <= CStr(59) Then

            If TextBox13.Text <= CStr(9) Then
                TextBox13.Text.Replace("0", "")
                TextBox13.Text = ("0" & TextBox13.Text)
            Else
                'do nothing formatiing is okay
            End If

        Else
            TextBox13.Text = "00"
        End If
    Else
        TextBox13.Text = "00"
    End If

    'If TextBox13.Text <= CStr(-1) Or TextBox13.Text >= CStr(61) Or TextBox13.Text = Nothing Then
    '    TextBox13.Text = "00"
    'ElseIf TextBox13.Text >= CStr(1) Or TextBox13.Text <= CStr(9) Then
    '    TextBox13.Text.Replace("0", "A")
    '    TextBox13.Text = "0" & TextBox13.Text
    'ElseIf TextBox13.Text = "0" Then
    '    TextBox13.Text = "00"
    'End If

    Call MyNewEndDurration()

End Sub
```

Comment: Why not just use a `DateTimePicker` and set the `CustomFormat` to "mm:ss"? Set the `Value` to `Date.MinValue` and then it will display "00:00" by default and you can get the actual value as a `TimeSpan` from `myDateTimePicker.Value.TimeOfDay`. You would also set `ShowUpDown` to `True` to have spinner buttons instead of a calendar drop-down.

Comment: or a MaskedTextBox.

Answer (score 0):

You say:

> ...and if for some reason the user enters 10 that 10 also becomes 01

That's because you are deleting the "0" in your code with:

```
TextBox13.Text.Replace("0", "")
```

Anyway, there are a lot of problems in your code so let's try a little bit different approach:

```
If IsNumeric(TextBox13.Text) Then
  'First let's get the contents of TextBox13 as a number
  Dim s as Integer = Convert.toInt32(TextBox13.Text)
  'Then let's use s for the rest
  If s < 0 Or s > 59 Then s = 0

  TextBox13.Text = s.ToString("00")
End If
```

Of course there are better ways to achieve what you want like, for example, using a MaskedTextBox or an Up Down Textbox with value restrictions to 0 - 59 or a Time picker control etc.

The problems you are facing in your code has to do with the way strings are compared in VB. Take a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/operators-and-expressions/comparison-operators) for more information. If you read and understand the "**Comparing Strings**" section of the article then you will see the problem in your code.

Hope this helps.